# Deploy jira plugin to a standalone JIRA using CLI

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I have a standalone JIRA instance running on my server. I have built a jira plugin using the atlas-mvn command and this has created a jar file.

Usual process is to login to standalone JIRA UI and deploy from UPM.

But is there a way I can deploy this plugin directly to the standalone instance using a command line or shell script.

Can anyone help me please ?

Answer (score 1):

I know the UPM has a REST API and you can browse it with the Developers Toolkit. I think its at /rest/1/plugins but is not clearly documented. You can reverse engineer it with Chrome, Inspect Element, Network while uploading a plugin. There's also https://developer.atlassian.com/static/javadoc/upm/api/2.1/reference/packages.html

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

`atlas-install-plugin -p #port --server #host --context-path "" --username #adminusername --password #adminpassword`

Example:

```
atlas-install-plugin -p 8080 --server localhost --context-path "" --username admin --password admin
```